# Page gets reloaded again and again

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am working on a firebase web project with javascript in it , before sometime my project was working fine on every single port , but now when I try to run it on the firebase local host , then it is showing some strange behavior .it gets reloaded on port **5000** and **5001** again and again , but working absolutely fine on port **5002**. I have tested it so many times , but same thing is happening again and again. I don't think there is any problem in my code as it is working fine on port 5002.below is the port listening.please let me know if anyone wants to see particular files of my code , as my project is too big to upload each and every file.

[image: port listening]

Comment: bheru baba ko nariyal chadao !